# How to merge two rows and divide values of chosen columns into new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a such a problem I'm not even sure what to type in google - if you have any suggestions or perhaps problem is trivial, sorry about that, I'm still getting there.

I have pandas dataframe of dtypes:

```
id    | string
title | string
a     | int
b     | int
```

Example values:

```
id    |title    |a     |b
id1   |title1   |0     |2
id1   |title1   |1     |0
id1   |title1   |0     |1
```

What I wish to do is to merge those two rows for id1 in such a way that I will have new column *c* where c=a/b, so

```
id    |title    |c  
id1   |title1   |1/3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First aggregate `sum` by [`GroupBy.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) and then divide columns:

```
df = df.groupby(['id','title'], as_index=False).sum()
df['c'] = df.a / df.b
print (df)
    id   title  a  b      c
0  id1  title1  1  3  0.333
```

With remove `a` and `b` columns use [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['id','title'], as_index=False).sum()
df['c'] = df.pop('a') / df.pop('b')
print (df)
    id   title      c
0  id1  title1  0.333
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df=pd.DataFrame([['id','title',1,2],['id1','title1',3,4]], columns=['id', 'title','a','b'])

df
_______________________
    id   title  a  b
0   id   title  1  2
1  id1  title1  3  4


df['c']=df['a'].values/df['b'].values

df
__________________________
    id   title  a  b     c
0   id   title  1  2  0.50
1  id1  title1  3  4  0.75


df.drop(['a','b'], axis=1, inplace=True)

df
_________________________
    id   title       c
0   id   title    0.50
1  id1  title1    0.75
```